# Backup/restore of a database that has a filestream

Tags: sql-server-2012, restore, filestream

I have a SQL DB to which I have recently added Filestream data.  Now we have a daily backup/restore to a QA server, and since I added the Filestream data, this has started failing.  So I modified the "restore" statement to include a "with move":

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDb 
FROM DISK = 'c:\somepath\mydb.bak'
WITH RECOVERY, REPLACE,
MOVE 'MyDb' TO 'f:\sql\MyDb.mdf',
MOVE 'MyDb_Log' TO 'f:\sql\MyBb_log.ldf',
MOVE 'MyDb_Filestream' TO 'f:\sql\MyDb_FS', NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10;
```

But this is failing with the following error:

> File 'MyDb_Filestream' cannot be restored to 'f:\sql\MyDb_FS'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

I've Googled all over to find a solution for this.  [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9195/6311) says that you need 3 separate RESTORE DATABASE statements, but doesn't spell out what they are.  The accepted answer [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS-SQL-Server/SQL_Server_2008/Q_27556607.html) indicates that you need to copy over the whole Filestream folder manually, which I find very difficult to believe.  And in any case it doesn't make clear what the process is.

Can anyone please spell out to me, in idiot-proof, step-by-step instructions, how exactly one is supposed to backup a DB containing a filestream, copy it to another server and restore it there?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the folder F:\sql\MyDB_FS exist, and does the SQL Server service account have access to that folder?

Comment: @MaxVernon - yes and yes

Comment: I presume you've enabled filestream features at the instance level on the QA server?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509097.aspx#BasicsFilestream

Comment: @MaxVernon - yes... but I think I have solved it.  The SYSTEM account also needed access to the filestream folder.  Posting as an answer now.

Comment: I had the same problem, and the solution was change to local acount sql services, change folder rigths and select replace in restore options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the mystery is cleared up.  The documentation only says that the SQL Server account needs full access to the filestream folder, but when I checked who had access to the main DATA folder, I saw that the SYSTEM account also had access.  I gave full rights to the FS folder to the SYSTEM user, and now I don't get this error anymore.